# can someone switch this to if statements instead of switch?

Tags: java

I get this error when I try to compile it on old java machine. And I need to switch to if statements? Can someone shed a light on this to switch to if statement? I get this error

> incompatible types
>   found   : java.lang.String
>   required: int

Here is the code

```
    switch(name) {



 String label;

 Rotor(){;}

 Rotor(String name){
     switch(name){
         case "B":
             conversion_chart = B;
             break;
         case "C":
             conversion_chart = C;
             break;
         case "I":
             conversion_chart=I;
             notch = NOTCH[0];
             break;
         case "II":
             conversion_chart=II;
             notch = NOTCH[1];
             break;
         case "III":
             conversion_chart=III;
             notch = NOTCH[2];
             break;
         case "IV":
             conversion_chart=IV;
             notch = NOTCH[3];
             break;
         case "V":
             conversion_chart=V;
             notch = NOTCH[4];
             break;
         case "VI":
             conversion_chart=VI;
             notch = NOTCH[5];
             break;
         case "VII":
             notch = NOTCH[6];
             conversion_chart=VII;
             break;
         case "VIII":
             notch = NOTCH[7];
             conversion_chart=VIII;
             break;
        }
    label = name;
    position = 0;
 }
```

Comment: this is not that kind of place, sorry. Couple of tips: 1. Get a text book learn Java basics, 2. Until Java 7, switch statements supports only int, byte, short or char, enums.

Comment: C# allows String for switch/case blocks - but not  C, C++ or older versions of Java.  "Char": yes.  "String" no.  So: `if (name.equals("B")) {...} else if (name.equals("C")) {...}`

Comment: can you write out the whole thing below? It gives me a compilier err

Comment: Java 6 and below does not allow string in switch stmt, if you are using java 7 this should work. http://java.dzone.com/articles/new-java-7-feature-string

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a String in a switch statement unless you are using Java 7 unfortunately.

Just re-write it following this pattern:

```
Rotor(String name){
    if(name != null ) {
        if(name.equals("B")) {
            convert_chart = B;
        }
        else if(name.equals("C")) {
            convert_chart = C;
        }
        // other cases...
    }
    label = name;
    position = 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I find these huge long if/elseif on Strings non-robust in practice.  Options:

Consider using an Enum.

Also, consider putting all the Strings into a List and using indexOf, then you can switch on the index.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick that I am using quite often but that may cause a lot of argues.

Replace expression in `switch()` with `name.hashCode()`. Then in each `case` where you have a single letter - replace double quotes with single quotes. In all other places you have to put numeric value that equals to hashCode() of the corresponding string.

Comment: Two different strings can have the same hash code.

Comment: @MarkByers Yes, I know this as well as I was ready to get criticized :) Well, in many cases when the input is limited to expected set of 'words' this approach works.